# Can't open project from TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Just migrated from VSS to TFS 2012. The server side migration wasn't handled by me as I don't have access to the servers.

The problem is accessing projects from my dev machine. I'm running Visual Studio 2012. I've installed Team Explorer and I can connect to the TFS server, however any kind of source control options are missing. If I go to File -> Source Control the only option listed is Launch Microsoft VisualSourceSafe.

If I check the Team Explorer panel there are options for Work Items, Builds, Reports, Web Access and Settings but nothing about source control. There's also no mention of workspaces anywhere either.

Is there something else I need to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in Tools... Options.... Source Control.

You need to have **Visual Studio Team Foundation Server** selected:

[image: Source Controls]